# Forbidden access when connecting to Apple Push Notification service

Tags: php, ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, apn

I have some troubleshooting when trying to push a notification to my iPhone using the APNs. I use a PHP code that I keep seeing over and over on the Internet so I don't think the problem is about it:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'mytoken'; // Of course this is my correct token here

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'mypassphrase'; // Same here

$message = $argv[1];
$url = $argv[2];

if (!$message || !$url)
    exit('Example Usage: $php newspush.php \'Breaking News!\' \'https://raywenderlich.com\'' . "\n");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', __DIR__.'/cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
  'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
  $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
  'alert' => $message,
  'sound' => 'default',
  'link_url' => $url,
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
  echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else {
  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I have the output "Message successfully delivered", so the connection has been successfully established, idem for the sent message. However, the device does not receive anything.

I used the feedback feature to try to know what's wrong, but the result is empty (the array is literally empty):

```
<?php

function send_feedback_request() {
    //connect to the APNS feedback servers
    //make sure you're using the right dev/production server & cert combo!
    $stream_context = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', __DIR__.'/cert3.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'meteor0405');

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $errcode, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);
    if(!$apns) {
        echo "ERROR $errcode: $errstr\n";
        return;
    }


    $feedback_tokens = array();
    //and read the data on the connection:
    while(!feof($apns)) {
        $data = fread($apns, 38);
        if(strlen($data)) {
            $feedback_tokens[] = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $data);
        }
    }
    fclose($apns);
    return $feedback_tokens;
}

var_dump(send_feedback_request());
```

Would you have any idea on what I can do to figure out what's wrong? Can it be due to the certificate? A .cer file has been generated from the Apple website and been imported into Keychain Access to make a .p12 file. Then, I converted it to .pem format thanks to an openssl command, and this is the one I use in files below.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the successful message then it means your PHP code is correct but something is missing from the pem file.
Checkout the pem file creation steps here https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm and try it again.
Hope it will help.

Comment: It actually helped, thank you! The problem was indeed coming from the PEM file. I posted the answer to the problem for anyone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed coming from my PEM file. To anyone having the same issue, here is what I did.

After having downloaded the certificate and private key from the iPhone Developper Connection Portal in the .p12 format, I had to convert them into .pem format. After that, I had to merge the two files (put the content of the certificate first, then the private key). This merge has to be put in a new .pem file, and this is the file to use in the PHP script.

Here is the full tutorial I followed: https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Moreover, the PHP code is not exactly the same. The one I used in the first post was not correct, use the tutorial's one instead.